# How can I deobfuscate this shell script?

Tags: bash, deobfuscation

I want to change the string into a readable code.

```
RDvmKMlDaaEXvrStCapvxerwITPSGCQymhhHBYgCylKANDKbhhkiiroGZvYuMlrCfEsJTTSfxDDFhhKKmOUdgocLkrWvRmLDuCzO="aXjurNdzTpvHTHVIEpkPqSZRaaNPbyJkFVHTYeignvUlajCYgALkQCEeVXVVzqjBiYUshDhWdMrwyZjgcViMLqvJXOvKWOdnYBZC";UWqSDMcrUYrYqxwZEbFeLRJfpOgwolmQEiFOyTOZAAiIkLNbfSkJdVLASIrporcMaffGfGMXRIifIDonSvcxAJrSFVDYZJUcuuCF="ENkegCJlJGBbjSWDeIbEpQZYOZIDqhNNedyFOehHToiMdZCgTlNhqCmGVKBRMaDZyxPXdctVyGUwCnUlQzLuyKGFjltLHxzBXDdG";ejiPLqystXNxYtUgGUmifXgEBYDJuuvbdfkHJJFoStvuChXvMFPqwxLhcfsfObdJvRzhfdvBxNuxxIWawIlKujAQemmYvaDEpZMA="ch";XtLyKRugMhglPWkrgtmVhoeFDScpBizKGTsUXbkwqWSPzRxunbECMzbMoFDXQhEwAmfoBGPqnBvBOmftaIespvqiMivZriNyjJPp="4";VZUMFCfJjLQThCqKatXyIFZYSAqBNaDtYUQCzPeGGsIaEUQsNzzLajQNNDlKxJAnMIexNlKUfXJBHlnjzwyiVNVwFNlNCUpeejdq="";uZPOPJKOjzyjFGukvbEtnKBjgmmyzffdyzpTGWzvvgzvdQAItImoTGRwCSqbaGFtCihauMWeChhYlBrVlKuVXuAndDMoDYIWEAKS="vxLODJOyHmTxkDVByipAyDKkHbZSLpbyABByIfUNFtKsLexCbGJxbCsWWfRanqRokaVcJaBNLVUecNtjUVSVQeHQYEbonmsfXoZm";ervmMcrZUygMcRSkJOEziALhPJEyPaPxmtpmNgwZOHRuTwnWUJXXHRpTMDAYqMFJRNxbmKOiWrXATPeSbSpnDRZTbXGnjOgWdjra=" ==gIKVXZml1cNFEdBV1cvp1YTF1YBJUQXhXYlJHVZN0a21UTXlFUnpFc2FUcJZHcsJVSClXTNBldkR0RzBnapx2SuREW5hESuhkU4JlUZlUWU9kQWBlWkJGcRxmWaxmSzJHa0NnRvRCbhZ0RvZ3RENFe1B3dhx2T3VHR5BHdZ10callRmd2VxlkUVF3Vth0VHNlRYh0a09kZjNWamZ2TRV1QDlVeVl0VuJVZK1EUi12Qtd1ZZdkUiJURaRXQYJ2cTBHe3h3Vr1WTt9kWkYESRJ0USpkWRV1QDRUQ6hFWHBlQUlkWapVWEdlRC9kUUBVUMJVRB9ERSp0RQZ1UJZleJlVSNl0UJdUQRRlQNpEVEF1QKVFVQJlePp1VUdUQQF0TLB1QKlVVWdkVWp3VIN0QQpHJlhmaW5WTypWUHxERJtEdZ5WeK5WaTdGS3p2bMRWVuFWTUR1dVh3RXhHaUdkdBh1UNZ3UH50auBnePFXVadmRvxUSqZEVpNHdZFmR5V1ZFpHR4xUdNFWRjB1cth3csdGcKRnTURiIgwWY2V2OpICUHhGaq5EaatmbKBHeh90Z0xEUxVWZa1EZhFkbjp2cCRlaGZnaIJ1a1xUVvJWR3lFUSx0b2BFeTdXVPhkZhdFeQ50dt5GdlF3VNVnTR9kbJFXctF1aX1mWjZHUNd0cUFXaEtESkE2TZd2aMFVTOpnUYNXaNFHZndlSttGdVlWWn5GVPdVRvtkRJpkYhlGVuBlcmNGVLRnZshVRyp1ZFlmZIdVStxGaVFnZQJ0ZphkU6R2bllVRGJlVYJkcGhXSWRHbFh2UjlmdiREJopVZkpkcxB3QEBVToZnYWZmdvN2ZDRkYPdkYQlmZyl1aOR0dp1GaitUbi1Wekl1TRpGV0lVYrhmQkZkVOhleTVlUEVkW2p0b25GayVHezl0ZKpnc3tGeVtkbOxEUwREUNFlbLRiS1VmZZNXTBRXQVN3baN2URNWQCF0V4FWZyRVWDtmdN10VZB1ZaBndBFXS2BHbSlkQ51UTQZHZEd0cwpWastkbEhVeIhkbIJFeSJVWJlFVPJkVQpFZiBXUsplWsp0cyhGdzZ0bkY3aGlkQLpWUTNmRiplcpNUcIlVTWRlcVJHRqBHbwh1YR5UcmBnY5RXVhBXTWtkWt12b6F3aMZlQatmWTtEUDNFTmNXeZVmeRZnYsZFT5V0bM50RTJ0ZP5UZVZGVUREVnl0ckpEJiJWcXZmet1EUzF1YTF1akZUahNUUTZEb4dVV3NmcPdGRsR0U29UbUVXTql3VBhVTix2RHJmQDdmdxdmS3JUYolnbDpWVOVXZnp2an9maMRneypXQmZ1TMJVYqpEdGVnUUhUVhRSYF9mVHRnSHpFdPNVcpFEUmJVV2J1cYFERC90SOhmRKNkZ0xEeCNmU2Z2Yrh3UQZXeQpmW1l3SXVWaGdVQLpXart2TkFFWi5GTSl2UTN1QHpmZlFFViJERBZWYr9EcMV0QDJUZkA1RohmaOhmWr5mSwhXYPdGdMBVclVmWNRWYB52YqNnQUpmR2pGSStWdMV1biV0dZBlUM9mdQh3U3V1TIZWYXhHUOdXbuRXZxdVT15UUP5WSxFXbRt2Vtp1Y2BVTHNHVxlGRLhEJWJWc4N1TFJ0Qt5GRYhXQQtmbOlkeV10Z0NmQqVHSIpkT1lXbstEdTpHSkRGdll3YYB1Qx1URDJFZOlVUWh1asJXQUtEekVUVtlHb1hXWoBHbRp2aUhFbWpWTTt2TIFXWCNXYYRCbhZ0RvZ3RENFe1B3dhx2T3VHR5BHdZ10callRmd2VxlkUVF3Vth0VHNlRYh0a09kZjNWamZ2TRV1QDlVeVl0VuJVZK1EUi12Qtd1ZZdkUiJURaRXQYJ2cTBHe3h3Vr1WTt9kWkgWZXFlZFNFdBB1VM1Edpl3ZRp1R0plVzRXYrJ1bpBFaTB3YmdFe0JkV0tkbEFGTJZUYTFGSQlUTw1UdpZmeTdGb1ZFbNpEZTRWdk10cUpVRudHaNpETJlVeapnQztkbjdkYllHJiJWcXZmet1EUzF1YTF1akZUahNUUTZEb4dVV3NmcPdGRsR0U29UbUVXTql3VBhVTix2RHJmQDdmdxdmS3JUYolnbDpWVOVXZnp2an9maMRneypXQmZ1TMJVYqpEdGVnUUhUVhRCUoN1QqNFUaFFRqlWR2JmcLJkZLF0TvFmVw5mV1RUZilWbmVFSrNlTWtUTiBFTNpkeVF1VDV0SFZVcz52Ss1GTUZmU2RVeZdWRipEcLJWZ2dVcO5memF2TvxEW1hnSsN2cXtmRkg0Z3JkUDBnUMFFasBVbJpGROJ2ZLRnV6p3dOl2YOJUYxZ1TlVVbL9EWlZ2QoF2YSpUcIRGdYtWWuV2UyR0Y2Z1aXdVT4hUcRNEWs5kU1ZHR6hUWXd1UTdEWwFXYYpFSaV3ZydFJKVXZml1cNFEdBV1cvp1YTF1YBJUQXhXYlJHVZN0a21UTXlFUnpFc2FUcJZHcsJVSClXTNBldkR0RzBnapx2SuREW5hESuhkU4JlUZlUWU9kQWBlWkJGcRxmWaxmSzJHa0NnRvRiYYtkWkRUQKxUdSRWb1h1bzRGZFZ0aKh2Qa9GTMlXZBdUbnd2VGd0RHVWe5N1ZNVVbSZ0U2l3QYRXbjhmSOJnb29kTp5mRzVVeNZXTzVVSCBFdzR3bRtme0RkTzZ3dhFEaadlekImYxdlZ61WTQNXUjNVUrRmRpF2QRNlRsh3VVd3Yy90ZExGRTZ3TtRVdNpWeXFEWNJGbHdkYCN0Z2F3ZKdnQhhWeuNkaV5Udldmard2bqxEd6JneBZmVPxkUhpmS0ZUdSRFSVFGJsFmRH9mdHR0U4VHc3FGbPdXdElHc0lVTzpVWGZ2ZXFXSSVVcX1GSXd0UGhFSrR3TmN2YpZmZPFVVDNUW5VVSX5mUlpUTQJWbD12Vnl1RSJmQFpFdBhlYzNFc4dHeXtWbN12TaRiIgwWY2VGKk0jRIFlQTJlSaFVVDNERBpHWYdEUCRVSaplWZR0VGJ0TSRFURxkUFF0TEJlSHBlVTlkV6lUWJ1USTl0RBFFVC1kSURUUDpUVUBlU69kWXR1RBBVQPtEUDpUWVZ1RWZleXh0QDBle7IiI9A1RohmaOhmWr5mSwhXYPdGdMBVclVmWNRWYB52YqNnQUpmR2pGSStWdMV1biV0dZBlUM9mdQh3U3V1TIZWYXhHUOdXbuRXZxdVT15UUP5WSxFXbRt2Vtp1Y2BVTHNHVxlGRLh0OzRWR9gHV7ICfgYnI9gWZXFlZFNFdBB1VM1Edpl3ZRp1R0plVzRXYrJ1bpBFaTB3YmdFe0JkV0tkbEFGTJZUYTFGSQlUTw1UdpZmeTdGb1ZFbNpEZTRWdk10cUpVRudHaNpETJlVeapnQztkbjdkYll3OiUmI9ImYxdlZ61WTQNXUjNVUrRmRpF2QRNlRsh3VVd3Yy90ZExGRTZ3TtRVdNpWeXFEWNJGbHdkYCN0Z2F3ZKdnQhhWeuNkaV5Udldmard2bqxEd6JneBZmVPxkUhpmS0ZUdSRFSVF2OiImI9YlYxh3UPVkQD1mbEhFeBB1au5US6VVTnR3YCpWdIhkSOVXetx2S0NleIRGZ0VWejhFUDFXTFNkUk5UWRZFWrxmcBR1S4RWRV1WesVHeZhGcsFlarRFWsZlaNN1aPhUcZJ0chh1OiISPlhmaW5WTypWUHxERJtEdZ5WeK5WaTdGS3p2bMRWVuFWTUR1dVh3RXhHaUdkdBh1UNZ3UH50auBnePFXVadmRvxUSqZEVpNHdZFmR5V1ZFpHR4xUdNFWRjB1cth3csdGcKRnTUtjIZN1VKt2SodkUo1GcSZHcZxGdplUWsJXaYdUZHxGcGh2QrpEZkJUWrVUWPRVYGpEUERnTRFXWEVWcNRVVQVmRTpkezhnbK5kZ2lnQ3VHbzFHVTRWQFN1SYFlTHF0cmdGZrRWQxJSPhl0a21marV2co1WWjRHdl5GTVZXYPZ0YIFEcitmQhV2czxUQ6JWTSpFaUJGTjF3TL92QjFXY1pXTLVXYEpneXVXdYxWRiJVerJmZOtGTiRmQIdEdMN0SB5GTi9UTq5mSSx0S5tjIk1CIi0TYPl1ZrxUUN5keSh1cp1Uckd2VK12a0VVaZdmbU90VF92SGlkSiFWaU5GUyZ2YUtEdmxGWFJnWnVUamh0VJ1GboVVcmBlQnlGSSpHZvVWWFZkUWhlQyZEeJZFdsVEaTNWa2JGR7ISWYJ1ZDlnYtlndipne29We2pUVUtWREVlcXVlcpJkUmNmQsdWYipGVKxUUhxGSHRUavBHTXZFTON0RSJWZnhkbId0cHV1aTZnWDdVYWd3SPNWdUd0caJlRJpHdphnWUZFWy9Uai0Te2l2TWBna1ZVQ6JkaXhkWEVUZEBneSZ0Rjx2S3pmelhnTWJ2UqBleGZnaKJ2bLFmbKdFaspGcwlUb2JnU0h2aRpUW4pFWGFWaM9GVPRFd6p2dKp0bi5UYDJVd1p1Y1F2ZZJVT7IiNi0jdrZUSCtkaRN1YGJmWyl2QxhUWNZFVyVlcEpGcsBHWjFlTxZGcilHdVFGcNZ1Sa1WbvpXcrxkVCp1aaN1SQN0UMZ2c5lVZ6FldixmVMlXRvxkTHNlQn9kTlVlZURFRUdWSzRmS7Iybi0DSndnQSNEcSxUUoxGUtlkaE5kYntEdWpne35Uaj5kQhFnVPVWVtt0TYVmZDhWYjJlSxhEZ0h1aZ5WZTJHRjZnVrd1VNhHSxF1QYxmTSVndEpHSZd1VTN1RYBXchhlWIpVdnJ3V7IiQoB3crdlaNl0VFdWRlF0VFNWZmZmUBR2UOp2YZ5GUiF1b4pEZjllYQREcm9GShlmRRJ1UFhUZtVlZBl1aZdEWt5ETQBHWRpHaDBVRhZ3VWJ3Q5JmbXFnU6VFc652ShJEeENkbi0zZldUe3d3Yyp1Yid3TBRGayNmV4BnR6BFSGlGRl92YCdnc25kVuVnRxNXbBBHVkFFbqFXTF5USOdVdn1mTWR1SsZWQTVmVk1UcJFFTEpldYlGbjJUYnNUVTRkTHVUTUdHZ6F3Y7ISbyxWb41kYyhXa1NleEZkcC1kR1tGWCJmeYJmezxmV3FGS5BXZHF1bp9kUC9mUtZUQ6xkdRV1UYFVYqpXbIR0bZZFcTZ3Q3hGRnlVUERlQKp0UYRmQtdld4h0RBpFUCJ2br1WQi0TbEpEekNWVBtWcB9EWOt2axZnRKBXS2tkalJHaOtGaXNFVqRkWQh1QRhXakFndJxER3dWUrJkSG1EWspldKd0ZuVVbuVFSUR1Y1FVYrpnZwtkRZhlZNRHV4VleI10Vnl2VLl2Q7IychJSPhV0bWdEdKdkW090UxlWQQZmUVZnUzhVQEJ0TL5EaGp0QmRHT4J0YSZnZjtGeTBld5BlaaVXeLdVZpZ0VBtkept2aPRWUYJmbMJVaTN1UDdkamVWUUJmQEFkZht2TwxURDNkQltjIi0DbhZ0RvZ3RENFe1B3dhx2T3VHR5BHdZ10callRmd2VxlkUVF3Vth0VHNlRYh0a09kZjNWamZ2TRV1QDlVeVl0VuJVZK1EUi12Qtd1ZZdkUiJURaRXQYJ2cTBHe3h3Vr1WTt9kW7IyQvVEd31EcX1UdqlkVyRVbtRWaLpkQBNGTYlFSndFaot2VoR2d3hleMt2arlnbMZ1ayV1QTJncI1me5RXZWFXb3p3c3Jkam5Ean9UWa1GaohkRRVVbO9ERDlUdwtWauZFVoh1Ri0jQoVHaKZmQZdXaUdUciBXeZhneSJHaDp0co5kT5JWakNlavFWd0VGchl1YwRGUvNER1Z2QCpnY4pGe5pmcKFlWHhEaqh2Qwh1QvBlVsBFSUJFZTlGe5pnalBVW6N0dUpWd2l3S7IicgwHIJNjV6NWa5kWYXRjdZ1mR6FWQwdHUTp0YNRUT6dleJVzT6ZEdJdGcoB1UKNWTE1keXpXT39keGRXSnBHdQNlSj1ERNp3V61EePpnR0l0Zw9GUTp0YNRUT6dleNl3T6ZEdJdGcyB1UKNWTE1keXpXT69keGRXSnBXaQNlSj1ERNp3V61EMPpnR0l0ZwpGUTp0YNRUT6dleNFzT6ZEdJdGc3RGVwkGWEFkeNFzc65kazhnYTl0SjRUR5kEb3dXT65kYNp3Y300Vwk2QtBDeQNlSj1ERNp3V61ENPpnR0l0ZwdXTqBTaYRUQ61UMzp3TUNHeiNVSLF2RrlTSsd3dNpnTi5ERBdTTXBTaD52b5kEbnRHVyUDbJd2bnllM4xWWYl0SadlTvJWeBlmSIRncmNVQnRDcXVFNwdVU0A3VRRDcXFFNwdVU0A3VRRDcXFFNwdVU0A3VRRDcXFFNwdVU0A3VRRDcXFFNwdVU0A3VRRDcXFFNwdVU0A3VRRDcXFFNwdVU0A3VRRDcXFFNwdVU0A3VRRDcXFFNwdVU0A3VRRDcXFFNwdVU0A3VRRDcXFFNwdVU0A3VRRDcXFFNwdVU0A3VYl0ZwxWWygmdJNUSrVmM0lTSDRUaspVRnpES0dXTuFTViJTOzNWeBtWZzIUMmZlWsNmbOBXSGJUeadVMwR2VwcmSIR3dN5WMLl1VSBXSFZ0aidFb1l0QBdmSIRncmV2SWt2UJtkWX50bilXQppES0JnZTF0Z0A3VSl0QSdzYEpUOSJjR1R2RrdmVY5Ebj1WNoJ2VVdmUHZUdJZkQoN2MkZ3YtF1alNTQ5Z2UC9UZXV0ZJNUQrVmM0lDNwdlUJdGcsllMoZXSDl0alJDd5k0QElGbaV0ZKhEd31kbxsUYXRHaJVEZoFWeCVVWYV1ZKhEdvZmVWpnWYl0ZKlmQRlFWOpXSHVTNZNVQnl0QBdmSIRncmV2SWt2UJtkWX50bilXQppES0JnZTF0Z0A3VSl0QSdzYEpUOR1Gb6l1UC1UWXVjbjNjV1pVeCVkYzQWdidUOop1QCVEZXhXMJB1QmtWWmdnb1cESJNkU3E2MzkGbaVUaD1mVqF2R4cWSpJ1NhNDMnl0TLZVb1tkVr90SWt2TLZ1aPtkVr90SWt2TLZ1aPtkVr90SWt2TLZ1aPtkVr90SWt2TLZ1aPtkVr90SWt2TLZ1aPtkVr90SWt2TLZ1aPtkVr90SWt2TLZ1aPtkVr90SWt2TLZ1aPtkVr90SWt2TLZ1aPtkVr90SWt2TLZ1aPtkVr90SWt2TLZ1aPtkVr90SW52UJtkWX50bidHcsllMoZ3QtZlahdEOLp1VO9mY5FUaKhEd31kbxcjSIR3bmRVQ4pES0dXTuFTOJNkU3k1MxUkYzQWdidUOop1QCZ1YyYVeKxmQoN2MNdGVuxGaJdGcsllMoZXSDl0alNTQ5ZGWztWZygWONRUSrV2MBlnZYBzZKhEdqZWV4ZnWywWdJZkU2JmM4pXSFVTNZNVSLp1VO9mY5FUaKhEd31kbxcjSIR3bmRVQ3pES0dXTuFTOJNkU3IGWxYUZHxGMJdGcsllMoZ3QtZlahdEOnlUaSdzYEpUOJd2bLNkbKxWWXF1ZMhVQnlEbzJHWWJkSUVEbJlERvdWSpJUeD1GbtlkRzdmSIl0ZQNVQ310UCRWSIhHOJZ0cnpESJdGUTFEeJZEM3Q2RoxmYnBneidkVsN2QBh3QtZlahdEOnlUaSdzYEpUOXlnU3EGSzkWaK92alNTQ5ZmVwsWZyoUOVJjVrl1V14WSFFDbidlSxEmMFdWUupkdkNjTsNWaJt0YygHbahVQn1UUwxWWygmdJNUSrV2MBlnZWN3alJDa5QzbpFmSIR3dN5WMkpES0lmZW5EcidkRvFmMGVXSFpUMhJTRnFlbKZHZz4Ebj1WN1k1UJt0YygHbahVQn1UUwxWWygmdD5mUsNWbxETZDFjdjdkV1xEWWlnYDFUahhkUwMGSNZDT5lTahhVU1JGSrZXTrVTWlpGaVR2UJt0YygHbahVQn1UUwpXYDJkMNlWN6FWQvtkWXhHcalmQil0QSlXSEBzZNRUSnh1UChjZDJkYJNkU5lERwcWTpJEZPNjUvp1V0s0Yyc2ZkpWT1NmMnt0QtZ1chdVWndVeBt2YpFUOJRUQ3lkRwcmZId3ZXlXQrNWaBlTSEF0ZYRFdwE2RWV3Qu50cadlV3lERFtkWX50bilXQppES0lmZTJUVhdkR1F2MNd2VXlTMJNEcmtUaJtkWYhGckF0bLp1V4pnWTF0SadlTvJ2dwxWWygmdJNUSrVmMolTSDF0ZJNUQnl0QBdmZpJ0KJNERpxWS3tWZzEEemV2SJF3USdTYINTaspUQrVmM0lzSDJ1Nih1MpxmNNtWZzEEemZFOrVmMxkDNwVWaKhEdyZ2UrtWZygWO0A3UNpES0dXTYNTapt0arVmMolDNwNVUJNkQrkES0k2QtZlahdEOnlUaBdWSDF0ZJNUQnl0QSdzYIFjYKhEd0Z2UFtWZzIUOYNlU3IGWwc2YHx2chdFaoJWaCpXWXhHahNUQrV2MClzV5J1NihFMopES0dnZWBzalJDd5k0ZwxWWygmdD5mTzp1VWdXSEV0SjJzZnRmaJV3Yyc2Sa12a9AiI9AFaTNkaTBlWRRkapVkdiJ3SCZ2SB90bhZFcuZVdEVmYp1mZVh0aT5kVL1kYQxUTKpXVRd1QFtURWF3cutEbtxEVmJldUlXWnVkYKB3SiVmdXFnTupnZh90bMhVd4pEbjN3VrZ0Oiw0UHhUdO5mSYtmaIZXWlFkQsFlSBB3VSl0aYZERHFHW5ZXcWt0SJtEeCJVQCNmV1hFZnhETkNmYGVWVthEdpFURItGUTNlRBN0cWR0cIFXcnJlaU9EaZhkWPlVYoR1d3ZHUpFkI9kVUSp1b3pHdNVFeQF1TH5UVDpUW4F0cLNGev9kQsdFRiZ2dYNVVLlHbUB3Z4dWctZmWUh3Ux5mbQVUTVV2QnlUU3ZHV3FnZmJmeJZFVvh1cLJUdZJXdMNHd3hXbVF3ZHxGR0x2OiISPKVXZml1cNFEdBV1cvp1YTF1YBJUQXhXYlJHVZN0a21UTXlFUnpFc2FUcJZHcsJVSClXTNBldkR0RzBnapx2SuREW5hESuhkU4JlUZlUWU9kQWBlWkJGcRxmWaxmSzJHa0NnRvtjI0ISPopVZkpkcxB3QEBVToZnYWZmdvN2ZDRkYPdkYQlmZyl1aOR0dp1GaitUbi1Wekl1TRpGV0lVYrhmQkZkVOhleTVlUEVkW2p0b25GayVHezl0ZKpnc3tGeVtkbOxEUwREUNFlbLtjIoNmI9IGWLpFZEFkSMVnUk1WdY92ckRWRGtmSoNkWvxET5VWQH12ZndlRHd0RllXeTdWTV1mUGNld5NEW012YopkTy5mdP5UauZ0cVlXT210cVlkQQR3c09WUrpHdE50c2dXYBhmWXp3OiEVdsZ0T5ZHdTdVdnhleYd0SLNmU2tGWJ50YWhXYWdFcXF3YEZkZKp2Q0xERjhWdE1EdQtkVwhnWGlmWap0YM9kbxF1aRJXZhRVdLFGew9kSGN1UjZHT4V3RJd3RDFVSOxkSXdlI9kHZjdHWE9GSJFld6FEUiJ0QSdXRVlmeClleytkbmVnRqZ0YDhXcKZmWz12URdmRCZGShpGSRRFbKpnWuFUesdUYkRHRnhWckpEdQN1aV1kQNZHWG1WaWxkUQNVRvBFZO5UVlV0Oio3dkRWeXhkcYpnTjx2VrpEeC12Rwd1Qv9EUW1mUop1alVne2hUQDBVSxNleC9WURl2aDJEdrJVTItUThZVaRxGUDFma6ZmVuNmZ4JnaUh2cNtmRp5UVUF2aDhGaaNVcDRnVRFlI98EaxNXZqplRMxGZDtWb0VWbVl0csVXbGZFeZllaTlVYBdHetN1cWVESaNkR0J0RYl1QYhVTCtmS2hkeSF2ZDp3dYpkQHFXcuZXVpN3T1pHdFl1aBJFZPhHe0FGSzJ1aHlmZSpmCy9GdjVGdvJHUoNXYC9yauNWZrFGdhh2Lt92YuIWdoRXan9yL6MHc0RHagoDIiVHa0l2RjoAZuV3bG9Fdv5EegknQgQWZ0F2YzVnZi90IKg2chJ2LulmYvEyI | r";otXyxKWEXcLWUalMFNNxKWWicmVvELQuFIaqdHThCPQRgOLvRgwwlFcIhlsaMeMXMSdouNuILedDnFUaFGjiwaMjhfHAcddUZEIK="VBpNgqlXUtgjuGpBJIxkKboHXNkypRgwZDLRlHFRlKOGArmcbPaMucHZcXDvkfngGQmvTPZaTvIXJnvVUyIMqgPbQEZAsmRSzUTU";hUcrxfccxzkiCFDXGKzlUdeYGRHTfuRWimutzYFXHBcKfQoZivVozBTDaFbKcqShsbnCfEdWtbZMHHxVTUYavRMfQoVyIMzyKEWM="";NNFZHbNBaxHQfEMzEVPKXibcpmeWgdtFKWfeYOSRMNVKLpiyGzxgwqodFKItNqRRMVmQrfjLWrhrDrDvGjwOPjrPrhmLcpHummNT="as";pRZkjmdkVrmjtsbaSGkSxHNFioKLhEetaLCIhPsWLdaUtvBMEUnkElMuspfwzaayizdRVGlQjEQmScVLchlfHMZUQzruPqnNtLkE="jxGbMyhxfIWnwJleymVyxpVcljPvduTWkrqwWTWzwiocJTCDtMrVjtFvTvoalfRhTrMtOFkmeuyiOJmFPEoYEyFrvhkiowDFNmFm";nTmofsNdRUwvMPLtbOXcHxdLmPPiaFcRXGrxKNECwiqgKsaNVvzFwObUDzXWDxEwocQjJrCgjpoVBGIFNcREePXDqYByiHOkfvOo="QXLpOMkwhJMHbeOYyZResUmlMBOIooZueZGnAdviasPJPPRmDCNVcCoaKPhauoCzMnFviFGxVOObAyfMYDebOMMyeAigQAftoOjT";vnPEKFFYIIqVjVcOruoNBVfssVDsqjyuqiimDrkmHLJwDvtxmiGfCmFJRPOeRtTbnhllAqsNZvbSqwnVBUZGSBqsrXtFDqOoZQNp="o";IYVIfpjLXeQNOtMPnUuyXLrdLIIDOFiRtUdYhoNdvLrEnqGuuvsulHHjGqjgvbYblRphRmZDhSdeEjTSBNwjgeZzDfBNOMtRcugl="6";tPmbuyHGuoMFpqQmsDVLsnIbgfFLXebnbcNrrNXVEICOCsZxLAuKBUEEGRiavKDNxqcYurqiRDLNMzlsXvleoFULSFbHnYMRXjmF="CJhNiDgMFipfFyBBzPxSIRaBLSspUfruEtkpKdqwavPyBIkWmuWIXfIWBgXvYcYujNydOcchdYivvddfCyjRgNxXtmnRiQptcpwV";pfKtsErsigpZnrimlanUwtcxufamyQwuRqrnVaLiVNGwspTJYTWPdAVePPmZgFFGAtqnVCFGbWnSIJHuKlfYurZWADEFtiAunRmS=" -d";sSOwfPMczgGfRKsTjbPKqjlINcJogahwqUNgcVwSKPprENwLtordItQtkPtMeJboHmALXWcPQRDidAQfdcISnOlihRHcpkcmQmHN="guixRFdUrJhlVuGkkGUldaOPTLXDhgCuXVBIwRSWecXpOaBJEPNiVISEzkYlFcrJkBGeRzwBIcRBLblleeemnvsGnjrSUVURCIBA";mLPzaWFYhvwrYMgQcRjFgSIMRAdDxgQPZbOORkGConfoOtjgPSpaTbCxjYEMWTSJESyoeoCnxYSsRDoxAymNCUmGMlWGVrSVnMsZ="";wPpaYvTKAJWRPgpFODYTcJGVwijZPukMpkNjeIZUKhXqeEECkzHPwPCRwpzHycNDoaKAAdqezNKjyVHdDUVHSsUEdeLuHkwhSJax="b";MlXgAKNipRUEqGFELXEWsbjjbkXuLPASEgTcHXxptccobGALsdnlGxWFelnwQIILAKIzzhhDmBddqsrlvhwjLcooqxcLWenbrtBw="e";tywSjFmQSdCkBaBkgRlioSwPiscQprLeqcXmEgoLyubhMrIYdAwADnaTARqLXHHnsQcwmkdNIaWcJPFErhjcRzWIyYrEFNltPfWi="v |";Tx=Eds;LhZpzYEGtuPsaSAamZYbDDvvrfQZXrMCbCLmgkLeVTwRZHiqBWgPmTNqgyDTLIEpMFqFPxPmxDXPWDgLldFOxfTjJIEwCukhHwie="";EWHIPIULTzHJITFZGMMZBQBLZDTHBCLzOXMFHzTKETHHBFORIJAWRKWEEVzAMJZJVSzQzLRPCCICAYIDJzSIOCNWMLDKFUSZBWEU=$(eval "$hUcrxfccxzkiCFDXGKzlUdeYGRHTfuRWimutzYFXHBcKfQoZivVozBTDaFbKcqShsbnCfEdWtbZMHHxVTUYavRMfQoVyIMzyKEWM$MlXgAKNipRUEqGFELXEWsbjjbkXuLPASEgTcHXxptccobGALsdnlGxWFelnwQIILAKIzzhhDmBddqsrlvhwjLcooqxcLWenbrtBw$ejiPLqystXNxYtUgGUmifXgEBYDJuuvbdfkHJJFoStvuChXvMFPqwxLhcfsfObdJvRzhfdvBxNuxxIWawIlKujAQemmYvaDEpZMA$VZUMFCfJjLQThCqKatXyIFZYSAqBNaDtYUQCzPeGGsIaEUQsNzzLajQNNDlKxJAnMIexNlKUfXJBHlnjzwyiVNVwFNlNCUpeejdq$vnPEKFFYIIqVjVcOruoNBVfssVDsqjyuqiimDrkmHLJwDvtxmiGfCmFJRPOeRtTbnhllAqsNZvbSqwnVBUZGSBqsrXtFDqOoZQNp$ervmMcrZUygMcRSkJOEziALhPJEyPaPxmtpmNgwZOHRuTwnWUJXXHRpTMDAYqMFJRNxbmKOiWrXATPeSbSpnDRZTbXGnjOgWdjra$MlXgAKNipRUEqGFELXEWsbjjbkXuLPASEgTcHXxptccobGALsdnlGxWFelnwQIILAKIzzhhDmBddqsrlvhwjLcooqxcLWenbrtBw$tywSjFmQSdCkBaBkgRlioSwPiscQprLeqcXmEgoLyubhMrIYdAwADnaTARqLXHHnsQcwmkdNIaWcJPFErhjcRzWIyYrEFNltPfWi$hUcrxfccxzkiCFDXGKzlUdeYGRHTfuRWimutzYFXHBcKfQoZivVozBTDaFbKcqShsbnCfEdWtbZMHHxVTUYavRMfQoVyIMzyKEWM$wPpaYvTKAJWRPgpFODYTcJGVwijZPukMpkNjeIZUKhXqeEECkzHPwPCRwpzHycNDoaKAAdqezNKjyVHdDUVHSsUEdeLuHkwhSJax$LhZpzYEGtuPsaSAamZYbDDvvrfQZXrMCbCLmgkLeVTwRZHiqBWgPmTNqgyDTLIEpMFqFPxPmxDXPWDgLldFOxfTjJIEwCukhHwie$NNFZHbNBaxHQfEMzEVPKXibcpmeWgdtFKWfeYOSRMNVKLpiyGzxgwqodFKItNqRRMVmQrfjLWrhrDrDvGjwOPjrPrhmLcpHummNT$MlXgAKNipRUEqGFELXEWsbjjbkXuLPASEgTcHXxptccobGALsdnlGxWFelnwQIILAKIzzhhDmBddqsrlvhwjLcooqxcLWenbrtBw$IYVIfpjLXeQNOtMPnUuyXLrdLIIDOFiRtUdYhoNdvLrEnqGuuvsulHHjGqjgvbYblRphRmZDhSdeEjTSBNwjgeZzDfBNOMtRcugl$VZUMFCfJjLQThCqKatXyIFZYSAqBNaDtYUQCzPeGGsIaEUQsNzzLajQNNDlKxJAnMIexNlKUfXJBHlnjzwyiVNVwFNlNCUpeejdq$XtLyKRugMhglPWkrgtmVhoeFDScpBizKGTsUXbkwqWSPzRxunbECMzbMoFDXQhEwAmfoBGPqnBvBOmftaIespvqiMivZriNyjJPp$pfKtsErsigpZnrimlanUwtcxufamyQwuRqrnVaLiVNGwspTJYTWPdAVePPmZgFFGAtqnVCFGbWnSIJHuKlfYurZWADEFtiAunRmS$LhZpzYEGtuPsaSAamZYbDDvvrfQZXrMCbCLmgkLeVTwRZHiqBWgPmTNqgyDTLIEpMFqFPxPmxDXPWDgLldFOxfTjJIEwCukhHwie");eval "$mLPzaWFYhvwrYMgQcRjFgSIMRAdDxgQPZbOORkGConfoOtjgPSpaTbCxjYEMWTSJESyoeoCnxYSsRDoxAymNCUmGMlWGVrSVnMsZ$EWHIPIULTzHJITFZGMMZBQBLZDTHBCLzOXMFHzTKETHHBFORIJAWRKWEEVzAMJZJVSzQzLRPCCICAYIDJzSIOCNWMLDKFUSZBWEU$hUcrxfccxzkiCFDXGKzlUdeYGRHTfuRWimutzYFXHBcKfQoZivVozBTDaFbKcqShsbnCfEdWtbZMHHxVTUYavRMfQoVyIMzyKEWM$VZUMFCfJjLQThCqKatXyIFZYSAqBNaDtYUQCzPeGGsIaEUQsNzzLajQNNDlKxJAnMIexNlKUfXJBHlnjzwyiVNVwFNlNCUpeejdq"
```

I tried use `base64 -d` and `bash <( gpg -d ... ) arg1 arg2`.

The output code that I want to get from the string should be readable.

Comment: Are you saying that the provided data constitutes human-readable text encoded in a way that is unknown to you?  And you're trying to figure out the encoding so as to decode it?

Comment: It's obfuscated shell code, I think.

Comment: Yes, @BenjaminW., it is.

Comment: what is the intent? if it's to hide some sensitive information it will be not safe because so that the shell can execute it, it must have the code to debofuscate. a solution may be to put the information in a file that is not readable and to source it through script which can be sudoed to user

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul - No, you don't have to de-obfuscate.  (obfuscation is not the same as encryption).   Obfuscated code will run as is, just the variable names were changed, random junk was inserted, etc to make it _harder_ to read / reverse engineer.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this question is essentially asking how to hack someone else's code -- if the author wanted you to have access to the code, they wouldn't have obfuscated it. As it stands, the author likely wanted to prevent people from copying/modifying the code, or otherwise reverse engineering it. If you do not trust the author do not run the code. As @JohnBollinger alluded to, it could contain malware, and you wouldn't know. Otherwise, what you're asking is morally suspect.

Comment: There are some syntax elements (`;`, `="*"`) that make me think that the string itself is not encoded, just very obfuscated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy to "de-obfuscate" this. First you need to save it in `derp.sh` and separate lines between with:

```
sed -r 's/;/;\n/g' derp.sh -i
```

Open the file and find `eval` stuff. Before that's execute, copy the hashes and echo it to the screen and exit it afterwards. You'll get something like below:

```
<crap>

echo "<variable 1>"
echo "<variable 2>"

exit;

EWHIPIULTzHJITFZGMMZBQBLZDTHBCLzOXMFHzTKETHHBFORIJAWRKWEEVzAMJZJVSzQzLRPCCICAYIDJzSIOCNWMLDKFUSZBWEU=$(eval "<variable 1>");
eval "<variable 2>"
```

If you then execute `derp.sh`, you will again an obfuscate script in the form of:

```
echo <a base64 string> | rev |base64 -d
```

This is how Léa Gris got to her answer. Here you will need to separate lines with `sed`, and again echo variables. If you keep doing this, you will get the the script eventually.

The final script:

```
#usr/bin/bash
p="\033[29;1m"
a="\033[30;1m"
m="\033[31;1m"
h="\033[32;1m"
k="\033[33;1m"
b="\033[34;1m"
c="\033[35;1m"
pu="\033[36;1m"
p1="\033[37;1m"
m1="\033[38;1m"
p2="\033[39;1m"
hi="\033[40;1m"
z="X-One"
 clear
echo "${k}  ╔══════════════════════════════════╗"
echo "${k}  ║ ${p2}Tools ${pu}Versi Premium ${p2}Jadi Admin   ${k}║"
echo "${k}  ║ ${p2}Ganti Username Dan Pasword${p2} Nya   ${k}║"
echo "${k}  ║ ${p2}Jika Gak Tau ${h}User & Pass nya     ${k}║"
echo "${k}  ║ ${p2}Bisa Langsung Download Dulu  ${k}║"
echo "${k}  ╚══════════════════════════════════╝"
echo
echo
echo
echo "${p2}{${h}01${p2}} ${c}Download User&Pass Nya"
echo "${p2}{${h}02${p2}} ${c}Login Tools Nya"
echo "${p2}{${h}00${p2}} ${m}Exit"
echo
echo "${p2}"


read -p "[+]PILIH : " r
if [ $r = 01 ] || [ $r = 1 ];then
sleep 1
echo "${p2}[${h}√${p2}]${b}Sedang Membuka Browser"
sleep 1
echo "${p2}[${h}√${p2}]${b}Silahkan Buka Browsernya"
sleep 1
echo
termux-open-url "https://linkduit.net/OW8sP"
sleep 1
sh v2.sh

elif [ $r = 02 ] || [ $r = 2 ];then
sh v3.sh

elif [ $r = 00 ] || [ $r = 0 ];then
sleep 1
echo "${b} Thanks You *_*"
exit

else 
echo
echo "${h}         ~ ~  ┌${p1}∩${h}┐${k}(${m}◣${p1}_${m}◢${k})${h}┌${p1}∩${h}┐  ~ ~"
echo "         ${p}[${m}!${p}]${m} pilihan salah ${p}[${m}!${p}]${k}"
echo
sleep 1
sh v2.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

To deobfuscate, you can replace all the `;` with newline characters to get something slightly more readable. You'll then see that these are almost all variable assignments; the second to last line is an assignment with a command substitution that `evals` a combination of these string, and the last line `eval`s that output (combined with a few more variables).

To see it deobfuscated, we can just replace the last `eval` with `printf '%s\n'`. The output of this is... still obfuscated. It starts with a hint to the obfuscator now:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Obfuscated By xNot_Found
#Github : https://github.com/hatakecnk/BashProtector
```

By applying the same technique again, we get this:

```
#usr/bin/bash
p="\033[29;1m"
a="\033[30;1m"
m="\033[31;1m"
h="\033[32;1m"
k="\033[33;1m"
b="\033[34;1m"
c="\033[35;1m"
pu="\033[36;1m"
p1="\033[37;1m"
m1="\033[38;1m"
p2="\033[39;1m"
hi="\033[40;1m"
z="X-One"
 clear
 echo "${k}  ╔══════════════════════════════════╗"
 echo "${k}  ║ ${p2}Tools ${pu}Versi Premium ${p2}Jadi Admin   ${k}║"
 echo "${k}  ║ ${p2}Ganti Username Dan Pasword${p2} Nya   ${k}║"
 echo "${k}  ║ ${p2}Jika Gak Tau ${h}User & Pass nya     ${k}║"
 echo "${k}  ║ ${p2}Bisa Langsung Download Dulu  ${k}║"
 echo "${k}  ╚══════════════════════════════════╝"
 echo
 echo
 echo
 echo "${p2}{${h}01${p2}} ${c}Download User&Pass Nya"
 echo "${p2}{${h}02${p2}} ${c}Login Tools Nya"
 echo "${p2}{${h}00${p2}} ${m}Exit"
 echo
 echo "${p2}"


 read -p "[+]PILIH : " r
 if [ $r = 01 ] || [ $r = 1 ];then
     sleep 1
     echo "${p2}[${h}√${p2}]${b}Sedang Membuka Browser"
     sleep 1
     echo "${p2}[${h}√${p2}]${b}Silahkan Buka Browsernya"
     sleep 1
     echo
     termux-open-url "<URL>"
     sleep 1
     sh v2.sh

 elif [ $r = 02 ] || [ $r = 2 ];then
     sh v3.sh

 elif [ $r = 00 ] || [ $r = 0 ];then
     sleep 1
     echo "${b} Thanks You *_*"
     exit

 else 
     echo
     echo "${h}         ~ ~  ┌${p1}∩${h}┐${k}(${m}◣${p1}_${m}◢${k})${h}┌${p1}∩${h}┐  ~ ~"
     echo "         ${p}[${m}!${p}]${m} pilihan salah ${p}[${m}!${p}]${k}"
     echo
     sleep 1
     sh v2.sh
 fi
```

The redacted URL at `<URL>` is a bitly-shortened link which you can't post on Stack Overflow; you can check out the preview for the link at https://bitly.com/2NXz8Tu+ (notice the `+` at the end, triggering the preview). It seems to download a file called `User Pass New . txt`.

Comment: You, sir, are too often faster than I am.. One upvote for you ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This was obfuscated multiple levels with https://github.com/hatakecnk/BashProtector

3rd level obfuscated

```
#usr/bin/bash
p="\033[29;1m"
a="\033[30;1m"
m="\033[31;1m"
h="\033[32;1m"
k="\033[33;1m"
b="\033[34;1m"
c="\033[35;1m"
pu="\033[36;1m"
p1="\033[37;1m"
m1="\033[38;1m"
p2="\033[39;1m"
hi="\033[40;1m"
z="X-One"
clear
echo "${k}  ╔══════════════════════════════════╗"
echo "${k}  ║ ${p2}Tools ${pu}Versi Premium ${p2}Jadi Admin   ${k}║"
echo "${k}  ║ ${p2}Ganti Username Dan Pasword${p2} Nya   ${k}║"
echo "${k}  ║ ${p2}Jika Gak Tau ${h}User & Pass nya     ${k}║"
echo "${k}  ║ ${p2}Bisa Langsung Download Dulu  ${k}║"
echo "${k}  ╚══════════════════════════════════╝"
echo
echo
echo
echo "${p2}{${h}01${p2}} ${c}Download User&Pass Nya"
echo "${p2}{${h}02${p2}} ${c}Login Tools Nya"
echo "${p2}{${h}00${p2}} ${m}Exit"
echo
echo "${p2}"

read -p "[+]PILIH : " r
if [ $r = 01 ] || [ $r = 1 ]; then
  sleep 1
  echo "${p2}[${h}√${p2}]${b}Sedang Membuka Browser"
  sleep 1
  echo "${p2}[${h}√${p2}]${b}Silahkan Buka Browsernya"
  sleep 1
  echo
  termux-open-url "https://sfile.mobi/downIoad/225843/22336/fa23affd3ddc2ee5f528cf577ded609c/user-pass-new.txt&is=af160f812e82bf5a4d7cfdfca7b4f65b"
  sleep 1
  sh v2.sh

elif [ $r = 02 ] || [ $r = 2 ]; then
  sh v3.sh

elif [ $r = 00 ] || [ $r = 0 ]; then
  sleep 1
  echo "${b} Thanks You *_*"
  exit

else
  echo
  echo "${h}         ~ ~  ┌${p1}∩${h}┐${k}(${m}◣${p1}_${m}◢${k})${h}┌${p1}∩${h}┐  ~ ~"
  echo "         ${p}[${m}!${p}]${m} pilihan salah ${p}[${m}!${p}]${k}"
  echo
  sleep 1
  sh v2.sh
fi
```

There are other hack tools here from the author: http://sfile.mobi/7ktplLidgc0

The file `user-pass-new.txt` itself contains:

```
        [+]------------------[+]
         | Username: Remaja   |
         | Pasword : Coding   |
        [+]------------------[+]

[+]----------------------------------[+]
 | Lihat Huruf Besar Dan Kecil Nya    | 
 | Ingat Gunakan Dengan Bijak         |
 | Dan Jangan Lupa Subscribe channel. |
 | Youtube Admin Nama Channel nya.    |
 | Tutorial Android-ID dan aktifkan   |
 |           lonceng nya.             |
[+]----------------------------------[+]
```

Comment: Was that the URL you got from the deobfuscation? Mine was different.

Comment: There was a bit-ly url I decoded to the real download file url

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for the effort! Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

The data you presented are not encrypted, they are *obfuscated*.  Specifically, they constitute a shell script that has been rendered very difficult to read by changing variable names to long strings of random letters, replacing newlines with semicolons, and underneath practicing programming techniques intended to obscure the intent.  The tip-off is the many substrings such as `="4";` and `="";`, which are the tail parts of variable assignments followed by semicolon separators.

You can run the code by putting it in a file, and running that file as a bash script

```
bash obfuscated.sh
```

HOWEVER, if you don't know what it does and you do not trust the authors and / or whoever provided it to you, then that's risky.

On the other hand, if you're trying to recover readable code equivalent to the obfuscated version, then that's a difficult task.  Obfuscation is normally a one-way operation. It can be partially reversed by hand, if you have the knowledge and patience to do so, or by a tool if you happen to have or be able to write an appropriate one.  But if that were easy to do, then obfuscation would be pointless.

Comment: In a previous job (where we had caught the competition red handed trying to reverse engineer our software), we briefly considered delivering obfuscated C code for one of our deliverables (to allow our customers to compile it using various combinations of build flags optimized for their needs).   We did some research though, and turned out that it takes three times longer to reverse engineer a compiled object, than code compiled with the best obfuscation software we could find.

Answer (score -1):

base64 decode accepts a string through stdin

try this

```sh
echo $ENCODEDSTRING | base64 --decode
```

Decoding it gives this value:

```
No printable characters found, try another source charset, or upload your data as a file for binary decoding.
```

Comment: is the result any different with `echo "$ENCONDEDSTRING"| ...` ?  Sorry can't upvote this in it's current state. (i didn't downvote). Good luck to all.